# Exhaust fan ground connection

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I am replacing the motor and reconnecting the wiring assembly on a bathroom exhaust fan. Somehow the older model came with wiring and not plug points so I need to wire and then change the the motor. I got a new Broan 688. However I am trying to not remove the housing so I don't mess up the existing assembly. While I can connect the black and white cables, I am confused on how to connect the ground wires. The space is really small so I cannot really undo the ground screw. Can I connect the ground wire from the exhaust fan onto the existing ground wire and twist it? I tried going through a lot of videos and I want to make sure I do it right. Thank you.  [image]

Comment: The fan metal housing is grounded. The screw at bottom left will ground it.

Comment: Usually those ground screws have a hex head - there may not be space for a screwdriver, but you should be able to fit a small ratchet and socket in there to unscrew it.

Comment: Thank you. I found another issue with what I planned to replace with. I need a different housing unit looks like, e housing vs d housing. Back to research. 